# How to enable soap extensions

Tags: php

Is it possible to enable soap extensions in php without compiling the php dist? I´m using Mac OS X 10.5+ with the built in php interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to compile it you can use NuSoap from PEAR.

But I'd compile it if I were you, nusoap is not compatible with the built-in soap and it's a  pain to juggle. Just do it right and start with the PHP5 SOAP lib.

Alan

Comment: BTW MacPorts is a great way to install this stuff without worry if you don't know much about compiling...

Comment: Yep, I'll go with macports. Not going to do anything that will cause any more pain.

Comment: For those who came across this post while trying to figure out why MacPorts' `php5` port doesn't include SOAP (as I did), it currently appears that you must install the separate `php5-soap` port to get access to it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you need to compile it because it's a core function. But you could try to copy precompiled php packages over your existing ones to put the compiled soap binaries and it's loading informations into the propriate files. Don't forget to make a backup!