# I am trying to use nusoap but keep getting errors saying I need to enable soap extensions

Tags: php, macos, soap, nusoap

I have never used soap or nusoap before.

I am using a mac with PHP installed and working.

I wanted to install soap but from what I could see if would mean I need to rebuild and reinstall PHP so I chose to use NuSOAP as it appeared I didn't need to go through the same process.

Basically I use the following statement to include NuSOAP

```
require_once('nusoap.php');
```

this works but when I try to make a call I get the following error:

'this client library requires the SOAP extension to be activated.'

Do I still need to rebuild and reinstall PHP when using NuSOAP?

I am new to SOAP so I want the path of least resistance to get going and start learning it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the error message tells you that you need the SOAP extension, then I'd suggest that you try installing the SOAP extension.

There is more information here that suggests/recommends that you install the SOAP extensions: 
[How to enable soap extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768204/how-to-enable-soap-extensions)